# Get repeating pattern using regex

Tags: java, regex

If I have this input string: {post:[matt]}

and I want to get the string where "matt" currently is, I'd use this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\{(.+):[(.+)]\\}$")
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("{post:[matt]}");
    if(matcher.matches()) {
        // pattern matches input string
        String str1 = matcher.group(2);
```

But if I had a string like this: {post:[matt,13-mar-2011,hello]}

how would I get the strings "matt", "13-mar-2011" and "hello" - when there may be a variable number of them? If it was just 3 it would be easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the find function, its supposed to find next match and next and next...
I dont know if you will have to modify your pattern or not.

[matcher.find()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29)